# Definition of the $M$ norm

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $||x||_2^2 = x^Tx$ when using the L2-norm.

However, what does it mean to have a M-norm:

$||x||_M^2$ for a given matrix $M \in R^{n \times n}$, eg $M = I$ (identity matrix)?

How should I see $||x||_M$ in general?

Comment: This notation is probably referring to the norm $$\| x\|^2_M = x^T Mx.$$ But this is only a norm for very specific matrices $M$, the matrices that are symmetric and positive definite. Note that when $M = I$, then $$\|x\|_I^2 = x^TIx = x^Tx = \|x\|^2_2$$ and you're back to the ordinary $2$-norm.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is what I actually meant...but How can I evaluate $||x||_M$  then?

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I evaluate" it? You evaluate $\|x\|_M$ by multiplying $x$ by $M$ to arrive at the vector $Mx$, then taking the inner product of this vector with $x$ to arrive at $x^TMx$ and then taking the square root to arrive at $\|x\|_M = \sqrt{x^TMx}.$

Comment: Why is it the square root? For any Lp norm it is the $p$th root.

Comment: Because you need it to satisfy the property $\Vert \alpha x \Vert = \vert \alpha \vert \Vert x \Vert$, where $\alpha$ is a scalar.

Comment: This isn't exactly a $p$-norm anymore, but if you want to look at it that way: if $M$ is symmetric and positive definite, then there is a symmetric positive definite matrix $S$ such that $S^2 = M$. Then you could see $$\| x \|^2_M = x^TMx = (Sx)^T(Sx) = \|Sx\|_2^2.$$ So what you're doing here is transforming $\mathbb R^n$ by $S$ and taking the $2$-norm in the new space which is why this looks kinda like a $2$-norm from the start (i.e., why there is still a square root). Also, as others have pointed out, it is necessary to satisfy positive homogeneity: $\|a x\|_M = \lvert a \rvert \|x\|_M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the full definition is
$$\| x \|^2_M = x^t M x $$
for $x\in \mathbb R^n$, and $M \in \mathrm M_(\mathbb R^n)$ with some additional conditions. Suppose for simplicity that $n=2$. Then $Mx$ is the vector in $\mathbb R^2$ to which $x$ is sent by the linear transformation represented by $M$ in the canonical basis. Multiplying it on the left by $x^t$ means projecting this new vector onto the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $x$. For example, if
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1&3\end{bmatrix} $$
then
$$\|x\|^2_M = \begin{bmatrix} x_1&x_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1&3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1&x_2\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 3x_1 +x_2 \\ x_1+3x_2\end{bmatrix}  = 3x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + 3x_2^2.$$
Trying $(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)=e_2$ gives a norm squared of $3$, which is exactly the length of the projection of $Me_2=(1,3)$ onto the vertical axis.

Answer (score 1):

From Trefethen the norm you are referring is defined as the following.

$$ \| x \|_{M}  = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{m} |m_{i}x_{i} |^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

It presupposes the $M$ is a diagonal matrix with $m_{i}$ being the weighting for the norm. Illustration follows. Standard two norm looks like this.

[image]

Whereas the weighted 2 norm stretches it

[image]